# Not able to translate the text in components which are there in Feature modules

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have a component in Shared module where texts  has to be localized using NGX-TRANSLATE. But I think component in shared module is not getting the JSON file which was loaded in  app.module.ts and I am getting the following error.
"Cannot read property 'Desc' of undefined". 
Also I noticed that the translate pipe and the TranslateService is working in shared.component.ts. Let me know if I am missing some dependencies.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmawme

```
app.module.ts

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

app.component.ts

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService){
    translate.addLangs(['en','fr']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('fr');
    translate.use('fr');
    console.log(translate.getLangs());
  } 

shared.component.ts(template)
<div>Shared Component :  {{Shared.Desc|translate}}</div>
```

Comment: @SouravDutta I am getting the object from en.json and fr.json in assets/i18n folder. I am able to resolve in app.component.ts as weill as hello.component.ts but not in shared.component.ts.  In app.component.ts template, I am using selector <app-shared></app-shared> which is defined in shared.module.ts

Comment: `{{'Shared.Desc'|translate}}` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your template to `<div>Shared Component :  {{'Shared.Desc'|translate}}</div>`.
Reason: all your strings(here keys) has to be enclosed in single or double quotes.

Suggestion: Try not to include SharedModule in AppModule. Because it eliminates the idea of sharing.